# Duplicate subNodes Telerik c#

Tags: c#, sql, duplicates, telerik, nodes

I am trying to obtain the subnodes of a route, I succeed but duplicates are generated as many times as turns are given to the foreach I think, how could I solve that problem?

```
        private void AgregarSubnodos(RadTreeNode parentNode, string carpetaPadre)
        {
            try
            {
                // Abrir conexión SQL
                string cadenaConexionSQL = Global.GeneraConexionSQL();
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexionSQL);
                connection.Open();

                // Obtener las subcarpetas de la carpeta padre
                string[] subCarpetas = Directory.GetDirectories(carpetaPadre);

                foreach (string subCarpeta in subCarpetas)
                {
                    string cadenaSQL = "SELECT carpeta_nodo FROM SEG_NODOS WHERE carpeta_nodo LIKE '" + subCarpeta + "%'";
                    string mensajeVuelta = "";

                    SqlDataReader dataReaderNodos;

                    dataReaderNodos = Global.EjecutaComandoReaderSQL(cadenaConexionSQL, cadenaSQL, ref mensajeVuelta);
                    if (dataReaderNodos.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dataReaderNodos.Read())
                        {
                            // Get the folder name of the current data reader row
                            string nombreCarpeta = dataReaderNodos.GetString(0);

                            // Create a new node for the subfolder
                            RadTreeNode subNode = new RadTreeNode();
                            subNode.Text = Path.GetFileName(subCarpeta);
                            subNode.Tag = subCarpeta;

                            // Node source
                            subNode.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                            // Add the node as a subnode of the parent node
                            parentNode.Nodes.Add(subNode);

                            // Recursively add subnodes for current subfolder
                            AgregarSubnodos(subNode, subCarpeta);

                        }
                    }
                    dataReaderNodos.Close();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Global.SuperLog("Error al agregar subnodos: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

this is what you see in the tree, the nodes are duplicated

[image: Result on the app]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you doing data access this way? Your code would be much neater and much easier to develop and debug if you used an OR/M, such as EF Core.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I didn't know about that option, I'll look to see how it works for me. As it is a software made by another programmer, which I am now in charge of, I am following the guidelines that the program has followed. But anyway, thank you very much for the info, I'll take a look!